# Plugin activated but plugin files nowhere to be found

Tags: plugins

I installed ThreeWP Broadcast through the WP backend and it works fine. But where can I find the associated PHP files? I've tried looking in the plugins and mu plugins folder of wp-content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go on your plugin list and hover the edit button for the selected plugin. Have a look at the url. It should be something like:

`http://<domain>/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php?file=<path-to-plugin>`

Comment: <path-to-plugin> relative to the plugin map, I should say. My problem turned out to be because a stupid ass FTP program that wouldn't update to reflect the latest changes. But this might be useful to somebody else who may also be confused for some reason... well thank you.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I didn't specify that. The `<path-to-plugin>` is relative to the `wp-content/plugins` folder